# Add shipping method programmaticaly

Tags: magento2, shipping-methods, programmatically

I'm creating quote / order programmaticaly. But when I do this, I have an exception : (in english, "select shipping method")

> Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException: Sélectionnez un mode
>   de livraison.

However, on my localhost, I can create quote / order. See my code :

```
$quote=$this->quote->create(); //Create object of quote
        $quote->setStore($store); //set store for which you create quote
        $customer= $this->customerRepository->getById($customer->getEntityId());
        $quote->setCurrency();
        $quote->assignCustomer($customer); //Assign quote to customer

        //add items in quote
        foreach($orderData['items'] as $item){
            $product = $this->getProduct($item['product_id']);
//            $product->setPrice($item['price']);
            $product->setPrice(0);
            $quote->addProduct(
                $product,
                intval($item['qty'])
            );
        }

        //Set Address to quote
        $quote->getBillingAddress()->addData($orderData['shipping_address']);
        $quote->getShippingAddress()->addData($orderData['shipping_address']);

        // Collect Rates and Set Shipping & Payment Method

        $shippingAddress=$quote->getShippingAddress();
        //set shipping method is not working
        $shippingAddress->setCollectShippingRates(true)
                        ->collectShippingRates()
                        ->setShippingMethod('freeshipping_freeshipping'); //shipping method
        $quote->setPaymentMethod('checkmo'); //payment method
        $quote->setInventoryProcessed(false); //not effetc inventory

            $this->quoteRepository->save($quote);
//        $quote->save(); //Now Save quote and your quote is ready

            // Set Sales Order Payment
            $quote->getPayment()->importData(['method' => 'checkmo']);

            // Collect Totals & Save Quote
            $quote->collectTotals();

            $this->quoteRepository->save($quote);

            // Create Order From Quote (exception here)
            $order = $this->quoteManagement->submit($quote);
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
    Need to add following dependency in constructor:
```

\Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\Rate $shippingRate

and then use the following code:

```
$quote=$this->quote->create(); //Create object of quote
        $quote->setStore($store); //set store for which you create quote
        $customer= $this->customerRepository->getById($customer->getEntityId());
        $quote->setCurrency();
        $quote->assignCustomer($customer); //Assign quote to customer

        //add items in quote
        foreach($orderData['items'] as $item){
            $product = $this->getProduct($item['product_id']);
//            $product->setPrice($item['price']);
            $product->setPrice(0);
            $quote->addProduct(
                $product,
                intval($item['qty'])
            );
        }

        //Set Address to quote
        $quote->getBillingAddress()->addData($orderData['shipping_address']);
        $quote->getShippingAddress()->addData($orderData['shipping_address']);

        // Collect Rates and Set Shipping & Payment Method
$this->shippingRate
    ->setCode('freeshipping_freeshipping')
    ->getPrice(1);
$shippingAddress = $quote->getShippingAddress();
//@todo set in order data
$shippingAddress->setCollectShippingRates(true)
    ->collectShippingRates()
    ->setShippingMethod('flatrate_flatrate'); //shipping method
$quote->getShippingAddress()->addShippingRate($this->shippingRate);
$quote->setPaymentMethod('checkmo'); //payment method
        $quote->setInventoryProcessed(false); //not effetc inventory

            $this->quoteRepository->save($quote);
//        $quote->save(); //Now Save quote and your quote is ready

            // Set Sales Order Payment
            $quote->getPayment()->importData(['method' => 'checkmo']);

            // Collect Totals & Save Quote
            $quote->collectTotals();

            $this->quoteRepository->save($quote);

            // Create Order From Quote (exception here)
            $order = $this->quoteManagement->submit($quote);
```

Comment: Perfect. (accord to my code, it's not "$cart" but "$quote" to avoid confusion for other users).

Comment: yes updated my anser

Comment: @HassanAliShahzad Can you please tell why we need to set the free shipping first?

Comment: @saiid because shipping address is required for collect shipping rates and then can continue these are predefined steps for order creation we have to follow them same as magento instruct us.
So that's why we need to set shipping or free shipping at same position where we require it. Its not our choice . . . . .

Comment: @HassanAliShahzad okay will share my findings on it

Comment: @HassanAliShahzad, how can we apply table-rate like flat_rate?

Comment: See my full solution here: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/320495/15474

Hassan is correct you need to use this dependency  `\Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\Rate`

Answer (score 0):

To make above code working(By Hassan) ,

Make sure **Flat Rate** shipping method is enabled in backend

Check that Country selected in Shipping address is selected in **Ship to specific countries** dropdown for **Flat rate** (In case you have selected **Specific countries** in **Ship to Applicable Countries** Dropdown)